# During Start of Debugging of KiCad happens the following error: Fatal Python error: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding

Tags: python, kicad

Description
I want to debug KiCad on Windows 10 with visual studio with kicad.cpp as start point. There comes the following appended screen.

[image]

Steps to reproduce

1. I start Debugging KiCad with visual studio 2019 with kicad.cpp as start point.
2. then there comes the attached dialog "configure kicad settings path". When I choose "Start with Default Settings" and click ok, then the application aborts.
3. In the output windows of visual studio 2019 there come the following messages:

```
    "kicad.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll" geladen. 
    "kicad.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll" geladen. 
    "kicad.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll" wurde entladen.
    "kicad.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\System32\WinTypes.dll" wurde entladen.
    "kicad.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\System32\TextShaping.dll" geladen. 
    Ausnahme ausgelöst bei 0x00007FFCBD0CCF19 in kicad.exe: Microsoft C++-Ausnahme:     nlohmann::json_abi_v3_11_3::detail::parse_error bei Speicherort 0x000000F626FAB9D0.
    Fatal Python error: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
    "kicad.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\System32\secur32.dll" wurde entladen.
    "kicad.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\System32\IPHLPAPI.DLL" wurde entladen.
    Der Thread 0x4e4 hat mit Code 1 (0x1) geendet.
    Der Thread 0x2c1c hat mit Code 1 (0x1) geendet.
    Der Thread 0x2778 hat mit Code 1 (0x1) geendet.
    Das Programm "[3368] kicad.exe" wurde mit Code 1 (0x1) beendet.
```

It is expected, that kicad starts and don't aborts.

KiCad Version:

```
    Application: KiCad x64 on x64
    Version: 7.0.10, release build
    Libraries:
        wxWidgets 3.2.4
        FreeType 2.12.1
        HarfBuzz 8.2.1
        FontConfig 2.14.2
        libcurl/8.4.0-DEV Schannel zlib/1.3
    Platform: Windows 10 (build 19045), 64-bit edition, 64 bit, Little endian, wxMSW
    Build Info:
        Date: Dec 28 2023 21:18:15
        wxWidgets: 3.2.4 (wchar_t,wx containers)
        Boost: 1.83.0
        OCC: 7.7.1
        Curl: 8.4.0-DEV
        ngspice: 41
    Compiler: Visual C++ 1936 without C++ ABI
    Build settings:
        KICAD_SPICE=ON
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this error is caused by setting `PYTHONHOME` or `PYTHONPATH` incorrectly.  You will need to create your `launch.vs.json` file as described in https://dev-docs.kicad.org/en/build/windows-msvc/